# Numba typing error when multiplying a single vector with an array of vectors using broadcasting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba, array-broadcasting

I'm having a problem applying `numba` to a set of functions I'm trying to optimise for performance. All the functions work fine without `numba` but I get a compilation error when I try to use `numba`.

Here's the compilation error I'm struggling with:

```py
Exception occurred:
Type: TypingError
Message: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot unify array(float64, 2d, C) and array(float64, 1d, C) for 'q1.2', defined at .\rotations.py (82)

File "rotations.py", line 82:
def quaternion_mult(q1, qa):
    <source elided>

    quat_result[:, 0] = (q1[:, 0] * q2[:, 0]) - (q1[:, 1] * q2[:, 1]) - (q1[:, 2] * q2[:, 2]) - (q1[:, 3] * q2[:, 3])
    ^

During: typing of assignment at .\rotations.py (82)

File "rotations.py", line 82:
def quaternion_mult(q1, qa):
    <source elided>

    quat_result[:, 0] = (q1[:, 0] * q2[:, 0]) - (q1[:, 1] * q2[:, 1]) - (q1[:, 2] * q2[:, 2]) - (q1[:, 3] * q2[:, 3])
    ^

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function quaternion_mult at 0x00000290EE6FE670>))
During: typing of call at .\rotations.py (102)

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function quaternion_mult at 0x00000290EE6FE670>))
During: typing of call at .\rotations.py (102)


File "rotations.py", line 102:
def quaternion_vect_mult(q1, vect_array):
    <source elided>

    temp = quaternion_mult(q1, q2)
    ^
```

and here's the full code of the corresponding functions:

```py
@njit(cache=True)
def quaternion_conjugate_vect(q):
    """
    return the conjugate of a quaternion or an array of quaternions
    """
    return q * np.array([1, -1, -1, -1])


@njit(cache=True)
def quaternion_mult(q1, qa):
    """
    multiply an array of quaternions (Nx4) by a single quaternion.

    qa is always a (Nx4) array of quaternions np.ndarray
    q1 is always a single (1x4) quaternion np.ndarray

    """
    N = max(len(qa), len(q1))
    quat_result = np.zeros((N, 4), dtype=np.float64)

    if qa.ndim == 1:
        q2 = qa.copy().reshape((1, -1))
        # q2 = np.reshape(q1, (1,-1))
    else:
        q2 = qa

    if q1.ndim == 1:
        # q1 = q1.copy().reshape((1, -1))
        q1 = np.reshape(q1, (1, -1))

    quat_result[:, 0] = (q1[:, 0] * q2[:, 0]) - (q1[:, 1] * q2[:, 1]) - (q1[:, 2] * q2[:, 2]) - (q1[:, 3] * q2[:, 3])
    quat_result[:, 1] = (q1[:, 0] * q2[:, 1]) + (q1[:, 1] * q2[:, 0]) + (q1[:, 2] * q2[:, 3]) - (q1[:, 3] * q2[:, 2])
    quat_result[:, 2] = (q1[:, 0] * q2[:, 2]) + (q1[:, 2] * q2[:, 0]) + (q1[:, 3] * q2[:, 1]) - (q1[:, 1] * q2[:, 3])
    quat_result[:, 3] = (q1[:, 0] * q2[:, 3]) + (q1[:, 3] * q2[:, 0]) + (q1[:, 1] * q2[:, 2]) - (q1[:, 2] * q2[:, 1])

    return quat_result


@njit(cache=True)
def quaternion_vect_mult(q1, vect_array):
    """
    Multiplies an array of x,y,z coordinates by a single quaternion q1.
    """
    # q1 is the quaternion which the coordinates will be rotated by.

    # Add initial column of zeros to array
    # N = len(vect_array)
    q2 = np.zeros((len(vect_array), 4), dtype=np.float64)
    q2[:, 1::] = vect_array

    temp = quaternion_mult(q1, q2)
    result = quaternion_mult(temp, quaternion_conjugate_vect(q1))

    return result[:, 1::]
```

I don't understand the unification error as I'm broadcasting in the multiplication so the shape should be irrelevant? All arrays are of `np.float64` so I've specified that as the type. The only difference is the shape but normal `numpy` broadcasting should work here as it does without `numba`. (I've added a load of extra brackets to make sure I was multiplying things correctly but they are not needed at all.)

I assume the problem has something to do with the creation of the `np.zeros` storage array, I've added this as previously I computed each column separately and then combined with `np.stack`.

My only other thought is that it relates to the `if ... else...` where I check if the single quaternion is of `shape` `(1,4)` instead of `(,4)`.

I'm a bit stumped by this and other problems similar to this usually seem to have some type difference involved, like `int` and `float` or `float32` and `float64`.

Any help is appreciated.

For clarity, here's an example that works without `numba` but fails with it enabled:

```py
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

quat_single = np.random.random(,4)
coord_array = np.random.random([9,3])

Note: quat_single = np.random.random([1,4]) will work with `numba`


quaternion_vect_mult(quat_single, coord_array)
Out[18]: 
array([[ 0.12035005,  1.51894951,  0.26731225],
       [ 1.56889141,  0.56465019,  0.18818138],
       [ 0.58966646,  1.09653585, -0.19548354],
       [ 1.15044012,  1.56034916,  0.73943456],
       [ 0.83003034,  1.80861828,  0.02678796],
       [ 1.15572912,  0.54263501,  0.16206597],
       [ 1.34243762,  1.0802315 , -0.20735991],
       [ 1.5876305 ,  0.70017144,  0.80066164],
       [ 1.20734218,  1.2747372 , -0.47177605]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these lines:

```py
    temp = quaternion_mult(q1, q2)
    result = quaternion_mult(temp, quaternion_conjugate_vect(q1))
```

you're giving the `quaternion_mult` different parameter types each time, so numba is confused how to compile this function.

Create the `quaternion_mult` separately for each parameter type/dimension you want to support, e.g.:

```py
@njit(cache=True)
def quaternion_conjugate_vect(q):
    """
    return the conjugate of a quaternion or an array of quaternions
    """
    return q * np.array([1, -1, -1, -1])


@njit(cache=True)
def quaternion_mult1(q1, qa):
    """
    multiply an array of quaternions (Nx4) by a single quaternion.

    qa is always a (Nx4) array of quaternions np.ndarray
    q1 is always a single (1x4) quaternion np.ndarray

    """
    N = max(len(qa), len(q1))
    quat_result = np.zeros((N, 4), dtype=np.float64)

    # if qa.ndim == 1:
    #     q2 = qa.copy().reshape((1, -1))
    #     # q2 = np.reshape(q1, (1,-1))
    # else:
    #     q2 = qa

    q2 = qa

    # if q1.ndim == 1:
    #     # q1 = q1.copy().reshape((1, -1))
    #     q1 = np.reshape(q1, (1, -1))

    quat_result[:, 0] = (
        (q1[0] * q2[:, 0])
        - (q1[1] * q2[:, 1])
        - (q1[2] * q2[:, 2])
        - (q1[3] * q2[:, 3])
    )
    quat_result[:, 1] = (
        (q1[0] * q2[:, 1])
        + (q1[1] * q2[:, 0])
        + (q1[2] * q2[:, 3])
        - (q1[3] * q2[:, 2])
    )
    quat_result[:, 2] = (
        (q1[0] * q2[:, 2])
        + (q1[2] * q2[:, 0])
        + (q1[3] * q2[:, 1])
        - (q1[1] * q2[:, 3])
    )
    quat_result[:, 3] = (
        (q1[0] * q2[:, 3])
        + (q1[3] * q2[:, 0])
        + (q1[1] * q2[:, 2])
        - (q1[2] * q2[:, 1])
    )

    return quat_result


@njit(cache=True)
def quaternion_mult2(q1, qa):
    N = max(len(qa), len(q1))
    quat_result = np.zeros((N, 4), dtype=np.float64)
    q2 = qa.copy().reshape((1, -1))

    quat_result[:, 0] = (
        (q1[:, 0] * q2[:, 0])
        - (q1[:, 1] * q2[:, 1])
        - (q1[:, 2] * q2[:, 2])
        - (q1[:, 3] * q2[:, 3])
    )
    quat_result[:, 1] = (
        (q1[:, 0] * q2[:, 1])
        + (q1[:, 1] * q2[:, 0])
        + (q1[:, 2] * q2[:, 3])
        - (q1[:, 3] * q2[:, 2])
    )
    quat_result[:, 2] = (
        (q1[:, 0] * q2[:, 2])
        + (q1[:, 2] * q2[:, 0])
        + (q1[:, 3] * q2[:, 1])
        - (q1[:, 1] * q2[:, 3])
    )
    quat_result[:, 3] = (
        (q1[:, 0] * q2[:, 3])
        + (q1[:, 3] * q2[:, 0])
        + (q1[:, 1] * q2[:, 2])
        - (q1[:, 2] * q2[:, 1])
    )

    return quat_result


@njit(cache=True)
def quaternion_vect_mult(q1, vect_array):
    """
    Multiplies an array of x,y,z coordinates by a single quaternion q1.
    """
    # q1 is the quaternion which the coordinates will be rotated by.

    # Add initial column of zeros to array
    # N = len(vect_array)
    q2 = np.zeros((len(vect_array), 4), dtype=np.float64)
    q2[:, 1::] = vect_array

    temp = quaternion_mult1(q1, q2)
    result = quaternion_mult2(temp, quaternion_conjugate_vect(q1))

    return result[:, 1::]
```

With:

```py
np.random.seed(42)
quat_single = np.random.random(4)
coord_array = np.random.random([9, 3])

print(quaternion_vect_mult(quat_single, coord_array))
```

This prints:

```
[[ 0.26852132  0.20522199  0.28520316]
 [ 1.89120847  1.35797162  0.79965888]
 [ 2.322112   -0.39389235  0.76960471]
 [ 0.51270351  0.3143128   0.24153831]
 [ 1.2691966   0.32325645  0.60666047]
 [ 0.85615508  0.20021656  1.01254022]
 [ 1.15864463  0.39780013  0.3251974 ]
 [ 1.17341506  1.41237398  0.29654629]
 [ 1.15734464  1.16277993 -0.14839415]]
```

---

According to my "benchmark" it should be ~30-40x faster than non-jitted version.